# How to loop through days of week

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to loop through each day of the week (monday tues...) and compare the day to a string.
I know I can manually add each day of week to a string array, but that's not what prefer.
Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**Update**

Thanks to Michael Liu the code goes as follows:
First on top of page:

```
Imports System.Globalization
```

then:

```
For Each d In CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames
   If d.ToString = "my string" Then

   End If
Next
```

Comment: What format is the string in? Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish what you want without the loop. Post what you've tried so far that isn't working.

Comment: surely writing this question was already more effort than making that simple string array? ^^

Comment: look at the DayOfWeek enum and cycle through that.

Comment: @FSchmidt It's not about more or less effort. It's about having less code on the page.

Comment: What is the end result you are after? Are you trying to figure out if the string matches a known day?

Comment: Also notice that DateTimeFormatInfo has an AbbreviatedDayNames array and a ShortestDayNames array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `System.Globalization` and loop through the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames` (localized) or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames` (English) array.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop:

```
Dim dayToTest as String = "Monday"
If [Enum].GetNames(GetType(DayOfWeek)).ToList().Contains(dayToTest) Then
    ' etc
End If
```